# Linux Alt + Mouse drags windows instead of selecting edge

Tags: edges

I just started learning Blender from YouTube. I got a problem here:
[Link to the Tutorial at 6:11](https://youtu.be/qqeNA_4O0Qg?list=PLjEaoINr3zgHs8uzT3yqe4iHGfkCmMJ0P&t=371)

I am on a GNU/Linux system with XFCE DE (XFWM4 WM). My problem is when I want to select vertices of an object (also, described in the video) with Alt + Primary Mouse button, it starts dragging the windows of Blender. Alt + Primary mouse button is also what I use all the time to drag windows. What is the alternative way to select all the edges of an object?

Comment: Yes I have the same question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to the site. There is a lot of information here. Most basic questions already been asked and answered. Use the search box at the top.